# set height of an element relative to the parent element - where parent is part of a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Well considering the following html:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <p>
      <b>content</b>
      (fills remaining space)
    </p>
    <div class="subcontent">
    test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

where I wish to set the width of the `div` `subcontent` to "50%" of the content div. (thus it flexes also with page size).

The following css "should" do it:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.subcontent {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;

}
```

however I notice that `subcontent` is now scaled with the viewport and not the parent div. This is not what I wanted. (Actually I wish to have subcontent exactly 100% of the parent, minus the parent's margin - and those margin I do not know beforehand, they're based on the route and thus based on javascript dynamic page generation).

Comment: you missed positon:relative somewhere

Comment: @TemaniAfif why would I need that, and where?

Comment: you need that on the parent element so that the position:absolute is positioned and sized relatively to its parent

Comment: @TemaniAfif if you make an answer out of it I can accept it :).